# Wifi doesn't detect any networks on 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04, broadcom, macbook-pro

I'm having troubles with wifi. I'm using a MacBook Pro 7,1 with a Broadcom 4322 wireless interface, and it theoretically works, but it's not showing any networks.

rfkill says that nothing is blocked, the module is up, and iwlist says that there are 32 channels available but doesn't find any networks when it scans.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** So if the laptop is plugged in via ethernet, and then I reboot, I can get a wireless connection. If it's not, though, then I can't get anything. Very odd.

**UPDATE II:** Scratch that, it appears to be entirely random... buh.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try adding additional drivers? open up **Software & update** and choose **Additional Drivers** from here you should be able to add the necessary divers needed to get your machine connected

If possible try connecting your machine with a wired connection then scan using the method I provided above. I've never use a Mac but I'm guessing it can't be much different connecting to a WiFi connection

Comment: Did that first thing, I'm already using the only driver available. If I choose "do not use the device" then it doesn't even detect that there is wifi.

Comment: Did you install the driver?  (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)  Also, after opening Software & update,  you may need to select the option "Proprietary drivers for device (restricted)"

Answer (score 0):

you can also go into the "Network" menu on the System Settings page and see the networks that are available. The applet seems to be the issue.

Answer (score -1):

kill and restart NetworkManager. I have this or a similar problem as well, since upgrading to 16.04 LTS. eg:

sudo killall NetworkManager

sudo NetworkManager &

Comment: The better way of restarting Network Manager is to do `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`.